# Google hangout bot (Apps Script) using service account for authentication

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, authorization, service-accounts

I’m building a google hangout bot via Apps Script and making a couple of calls to google apis, my problem is that the bot currently requests permissions from bot users when I thought I had it set up correctly to call Google APIs on behalf of the service account rather than the user.

I followed the guidance provided by google here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account

- I created a short lived JWT and verified the signature at https://jwt.io/
- I then make a post request to https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token and an access token is included in the response which I have verified via https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo.

Response is:

```
{
   "azp": "XXXXXX", // Google service account id
   "aud": "XXXXXX", // Google service account id
   "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
   "exp": "1629819391",
   "expires_in": "3569",
   "access_type": "online"
}
```

- I then use the google access token to call the api

Here is the code:

```
/*
 * 1. BUILD RS256 JWT: HEADER, CLAIM SET, SIGNATURE
 */
const createJwt = ({ privateKey, expiresInHours, input = {} }) => {      
  /*
  * The only signing algorithm supported by the Google OAuth 2.0 Authorization Server is RSA using SHA-256 hashing algorithm. 
  * This is expressed as RS256 in the alg field in the JWT header.
  */
  const header = { 
                    "alg":"RS256", 
                    "typ":"JWT", 
                    "kid": "XXXXXX", // service account private_key_id
                    "x5c": SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PUBLIC_KEY
                  };

  const now = Date.now();
  const expires = new Date(now);
  expires.setHours(expires.getHours() + expiresInHours);

  /*
  * iat: issued time 
  * exp: expiration time
  */
  const payload = {
    iat: Math.round(now / 1000),
    exp: Math.round(expires.getTime() / 1000)
  };

  /* add payload / claim set */
  Object.keys(input).forEach(function (key) {
    payload[key] = input[key];
  });

  const base64Encode = (text, json = true) => {
    const input = json ? JSON.stringify(text) : text;
    return Utilities.base64EncodeWebSafe(input).replace(/=+$/, '');
  };

  /* encode using the Base64url encoding */
  const toSign = `${base64Encode(header)}.${base64Encode(payload)}`;
  
  /*
  * Sign the UTF-8 representation of the input using SHA256withRSA (also known as RSASSA-PKCS1-V1_5-SIGN with the SHA-256 hash function) 
  * with the private key obtained from the Google API Console. 
  */
  const signatureBytes = Utilities.computeRsaSha256Signature(
    toSign,
    privateKey
  );
  
  /* The signature must then be Base64url encoded */
  const signature = base64Encode(signatureBytes, false);

  return `${toSign}.${signature}`;
};


/*
 * 2. SET JWT SCOPES & EXPIRY DATE
 * must be a short lived access token e.g. 1 hour, or else oauth2.googleapis.com/token throws an error
 */
const generateAccessToken = () => {
  const privateKey = SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PRIVATE_KEY;
  const scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/chat.bot", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly"];
  
  const accessToken = createJwt({
    privateKey,
    expiresInHours: 1,
    input: {
      iss: SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL,
      scope: scopes.join(" "),
      aud: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
    },
  });
  Logger.log(accessToken);
  return accessToken;
};


/*
 * 3. GENERATE JWT
 */
const jwt = generateAccessToken();

/*
 * 4. USE JWT TO GET GOOGLE ACCESS TOKEN FROM THE GOOGLE AUTHORIZATION SERVER
 */
const getGoogleAccessToken = () => UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token", {
  method: "post",
  contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  payload: "grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=" + jwt
});
```

Example calling api

```
/**
 * Posts a message into the given space ID via the API,
 * using service account authentication.
 */
function postMessage(spaceId, message) {
  
 const CHAT_SPACE_URL = 'https://chat.googleapis.com/v1/spaces/' + spaceId + '/messages';
  
  Logger.log(JSON.parse(getGoogleAccessToken()));
  
 UrlFetchApp.fetch(CHAT_SPACE_URL, {
    method: 'post',
    headers: { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + JSON.parse(getGoogleAccessToken()).access_token },
    contentType: 'application/json',
    payload: JSON.stringify(message),
  });
  
  
}
```

Any help in where I'm going wrong is much appreciated :)

Comment: Have you removed your token file and re-created it?

Comment: @RafaGuillermoI I did rename the file the tokens are generated in, is there another step in the process I need to make for the update to be implemented?

Answer (score -1):

Just to let you know I found the issue is internal at our company, we are unable to add the OAuth scopes via the Google Workspace domains Admin console. This code will work with delegating domain-wide authority implemented and so I'll leave the question here in case it helps someone else.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.